# Why jetbrains writes error

Tags: webpack, jetbrains-ide

I installed jetbrains and opened his project, but he always emphasizes the word and says that it is an error. How can I fix this?

By the way, I use webpack through the terminal, how do I integrate it into jetbrains?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit Alt+Enter on the statement, choose to *Switch JavaScript Language version to ECMAScript 6*:

[image]

Or, you can switch the version manually in `Settings(Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript, JavaScript Language version`

No dedicated WebPack integration is provided; but you can run WebPack as npm script from NPM panel, or create a Node.js run configuration to run it, or integrate it as External Tool - it depends on your preferences.

Comment: sorry,  when I open file it's not open, jetbrains write "Loading.."

Comment: sorry, what file?